# Change Rcode for a meta-regression model of a meta-analysis to use a random effects model instead of a mixed effects model

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am writing a meta-analysis that compares the complication rates and reoperation rates of 5 treatment modalities after a distal radius fracture by metaregression. But the metaregression uses a mixed effects model(the default model). How can I change the code to use a random effects model?

```
library(meta)
library(readxl)

All <- read_excel("Basics excel file complication and reoperation rate.xlsx", sheet=1)
names(All) <- c("Study_ID","Event_Type","Treatment","Events_n","N","nN")
All$Treatment <- factor(All$Treatment, levels=c("PC","EF","IMN","KW","VPO"))

# Outcomes
Complications <- subset(All, Event_Type=="Complications")
Reoperations <- subset(All, Event_Type=="Reoperations")

# Comparison of treatment effects to gold standard in the Complications subset
mtpr1 <- metaprop(Events_n, N, Study_ID, data = Complications)
meta::metareg(mtpr1, ~Treatment)

# Comparison of treatment effects to gold standard in the Reoperations subset
mtpr2 <- metaprop(Events_n, N, Study_ID, data = Reoperations)
meta::metareg(mtpr2, ~Treatment)

# Comparison of treatment effects to gold standard in the All dataset
# Interaction effects have been considered
mtpr <- metaprop(Events_n, N, Study_ID, data = All)
meta::metareg(mtpr, ~Treatment*Event_Type)
```

A part of the dataset:

```
Study| Event Type| Treatment| Number of Events (n)| N| n/N|
Kumaravel| Complications| EF| 3| 23| 0,1304348|
Franck| Complications| EF| 2| 20| 0,1|
Schonnemann| Complications| EF| 8| 30| 0,2666667|
Aita| Complications| EF| 1| 16| 0,0625|
Hove| Complications| EF| 31| 39| 0,7948718|
Andersen| Complications| EF| 26| 75| 0,3466667|
Krughaug| Complications| EF| 22| 75| 0,2933333|
Moroni| Complications| EF| 0| 20| 0|
Plate| Complications| IMN| 3| 30| 0,1|
Chappuis| Complications| IMN| 4| 16| 0,25|
Gradl| Complications| IMN| 12| 66| 0,1818182|
Schonnemann| Complications| IMN| 6| 31| 0,1935484|
Aita| Complications| IMN| 1| 16| 0,0625|
Dremstrop| Complications| IMN| 17| 44| 0,3863636|
Wong| Complications| PC| 1| 30| 0,0333333|
Kumaravel| Complications| PC| 4| 25| 0,16|
```

Comment: @Joris Meys thank you for your response. How could I change the R code for a fully random effects model?

Comment: as I explained, by removing the fixed terms. Which is not what you want to do, so why do you insist on a random model?

Comment: @Joris Meys I want to see what the difference would be of either using a random or fixed effects model across subgroups. And a random effects model allows us to infer what the effects might by in other subgroups, by assuming it comes from the same random effects distribution. What is the fixed effects part of the code?

Comment: then you have to use a random model (eg the `lme4` package), not a metaregression. And keep in mind you can't compare both models, as they're not nested and are based on different assumptions and parametrization. In the context of a meta-regression, your moderators are used as a fixed effect. The `meta` package is actually built on the `metafor` package, and the functions `rma` and `rma.uni` are the ones you can look at to get more information on the fitting process.

Comment: You're welcome. Also keep in mind that in the context of meta-analysis, "fixed" and "random" model has a specific meaning. The difference lies in the underlying distribution of the study effects, and has especially an impact on how studies are weighted and on the confidence interval around the combined effect size. As 'study' is nested within 'treatment', using 'study' as a random effect essentially catches the extra variation caused by `treatment`.

Comment: @Joris Meys I would like to ask you one more question. To compare the complication and reoperation rates of different treatment methods, would you use a meta-regression analysis or would you do a network meta-analysis (since the studies have different treatment arms and number of arms) and why?

Comment: As far as I can see you are doing a random-effects meta-analysis.